# Git: How to clone project without losing the current branches?

Tags: java, git, github, version-control, gitlab

I have a project in my local Git repository and there is a problem in the project that is not fixed after lots of pull from origin etc. So, I need to clone the project from origin without losing the branches in the project (in local repository). So, what is the best approach for this kind of situations? Because sometimes I have seen this problem and fix the problem by deleting project completely on local repo and cloning from remote repo.

Comment: "There is a problem" is not, by itself, a useful StackOverflow question: see [ask].

Comment: @torek If you read question, you can see the problem and may be understand. After that, any idea regarding to the problem?

Comment: Still can't see the actual problem. You've decided on a solution: make another clone. You asked about making other clones. You still haven't explained the actual *problem*. See also [What is the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to delete a project completely on your local repo just to clone from the remote repo. If you really want to do that you could just try creating a new local repo and then clone from the remote repo and then you will still have all of your other branches in the original local repo.

I would recommend trying `git reset --hard origin/master` to see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already tried it, but does no make any sense. Any other suggestion without losing current local branches?